# Is JDBC multi-threaded insert possible?

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc, insert-update

I'm currently working on a Java project which i need to prepare a big(to me) mysql database. I have to do web scraping using Jsoup and store the results into my database as well. As i estimated, i will have roughly 1,500,000 to 2,000,000 records to be inserted. In my first trial, i just use a loop to insert these records and it takes me one week to insert about 1/3 of my required records, which is too slow i think. Is it possible to make this process multi-threaded, so that i can have my records split into 3 sets, say 500,000 records per set, and then insert them into one database( one table specifically)?

Comment: Are you 100% sure it's the DB that's the bottleneck here? If you replace the inserts with a dummy call, how long does it take?

Comment: Thanks for your concern. basically, my program just do batch updates to the database after crawling neccessary data. As i don't have much experience in Java, i just do this sequentially, like crawling->batch update per 500 records->crawling->update...and so on. As i do print some messages at those key steps, i can see that most of the time the program was stuck in the database update part for long time. say it takes about 1 to 2 mins to finish each crawling but about 15 mins to finish database update every time.

Comment: 15 minutes to finish database update of 500 records? There must be something horribly wrong with your setup... 500 records is almost nothing... please double check that database is really where the time is spent. Also try to monitor the hardware usage (memory, cpu, disk usage) during the update if the hardware isn't bottleneck. Finally, if you are using Hibernate or different ORM, try to fine tune it or try to switch to pure JDBC and utilize addBatch() as described for example here: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2356497

Answer (score 7):

Multi-threading isn't going to help you here. You'll just move the contention bottleneck from your app server to the database.

Instead, try using batch-inserts instead, they generally make this sort of thing orders of magnitude faster.  See ["3.4 Making Batch Updates" in the JDBC tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/JDBCTutorial/index.html).

*Edit*: As @Jon commented, you need to decouple the fetching of the web pages from their insertion into the database, otherwise the whole process will go at the speed of the slowest operation. You could have multiple threads fetching web pages, which add the data to a queue data structure, and then have a single thread draining the queue into the database using a batch insert.

Comment: this sounds like an app where lots of time is spent waiting for http-responses. more threads are likely to help, but if the pages are served up really incredibly quick with very low latency the gain might not be very large.

Comment: Right, that is my question.  Are you sure the bottleneck is the DB and not the web-crawling?  Sounds like crawling the web and parsing would take much more time than the inserts.  If the inserts are really the issue, i would recommend having the crawler dump data into a text file that can be bulk imported into mysql.  it shouldn't take more than an hour to two at most to bulk load 2 million rows.

Comment: @skaffman "you need to decouple the fetching of the web pages" i agree, multithreading the inserts won't help much by itself, it's the webscraping that probably slows everything down. but i think it'd be easier just to let the inserts run in the same threads as the webscraping producing them. decoupling would require jdbc-inserts to run in a separate thread, and there would be queuing and synchronization issues to take care of.

Comment: thanks for all your advices. basically, my program just do batch updates to the database after crawling neccessary data. As i don't have much experience in Java, i just do this sequentially,  like crawling->batch update per 500 records->crawling->update...and so on. As i do print some messages at those key steps, i can see that most of the time the program was stuck in the database update part for long time. say it takes about 1 to 2 mins to finish each crawling but about 15 mins to finish database update every time.

Comment: What caught my attention is a. 1 to 2 minutes to crawl, does a crawl result in a "single" or "multiple" updates (can you quantify) number of updates per crawl?, I don't think 1.5 to 2 million is such a big data base, I was wondering if you'r data model is optimized (indexes etc). I would look there too.

Comment: I think the same, I would expect the crawling being slower than the database inserts (though I don't really know what is crawled and what is inserted). MAYBE the database isn't properly tuned? PostgreSQL for instance comes  with pretty conservative default sizes for buffers and caches ...

Comment: Link seems to have died.  As I'm sure there is plenty of usefull information in there... can I suggest replacing it to make the answer still relevant.

Comment: "Multi-threading isn't going to help you here." Why not? Is multi-threading inserts into a DB via jdbc a no-go in general? I have a similar problem with inserting lots of PDF-files (blobs) into one Oracle Table.  Grateful for an authoritative source.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure two (or more) threads doesn't use the same connection at the same time, using a connection pool resolves that. c3po and apache dbcp comes to mind ...

Answer (score 1):

You can chunk your record set into batches and do this, but perhaps you should think about other factors as well.

Are you doing a network round trip  for each INSERT?  If yes, latency could be the real enemy.  Try batching those requests to cut down on network traffic.

Do you have transactions turned on?  If yes, the size of the rollback log could be the problem.

I'd recommend profiling the app server and the database server to see where the time is being spent.  You can waste a lot of time guessing about the root cause.

Comment: thanks. I have already use BatchUpdate/PreparedStatements(Do i get it wrongly?)...but i'm not satisified abt the performance, you know it takes 1 week to insert 1/3 of the records, which is quick unacceptable to me( and more importantly, my boss )

Answer (score 1):

You can insert these records in different threads provided they do use different primary key values.

You should also look at [Spring Batch](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/) which I believe will be useful in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I think multi thread approch usefull for your issue but you have to using a [`connection pool`](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cts=1331546671769&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html&ei=LMpdT__YBYrLtAbcl7yoDA&usg=AFQjCNFadGFRl2IS4iGLDC3SrmXTik6kUQ&sig2=sXizllDDMy5Tycz2UZruqQ) such as [`C3P0`](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cts=1331546603498&ved=0CEAQFjAB&url=http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html&ei=5MldT-OOGInVtAansOSiBQ&usg=AFQjCNExN_9iOXY3X2BqKp7KLHeTOZMCPQ&sig2=hDI4vA26Xrff5ULXgdyK7Q) or `Tomca 7 Connetcion pool` for more performance.

Another solution is using a batch-operation provider such as  [`Spring-batch`](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cts=1331546706024&sqi=2&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/&ei=T8pdT8adIs7otQaF4MicDA&usg=AFQjCNGuZXnB9IISNNUN8yaL8d_o78Ia4w&sig2=bdBvFEB3JMkp6PMr3-W7Pg), exist anothers utility for batch operation also.

Another solution is using a `PL/SQl Procedure` with a input `structure` parameter.